# PostgreSQL Count DISTINCT from one column when grouped by another

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have a single table that looks like the following (dumbed down):

```
userid   |   action    |    userstate
-----------------------------------------------------
1        | click       |    Maryland
2        | press       |    Delaware
3        | jog         |    New York
3        | leap        |    New York
```

What I'm trying to query is "number of users doing ANY action, per state"

So the result would be:

```
state |  users_acting
---------------------
Maryland |    1
Delaware |    1
New York |    1
```

Note that individual users will only be part in one state.

I can't get the mix of distinct users correct with grouping by state.  I can't

```
SELECT DISTINCT (userid), COUNT(userid) FROM data GROUP BY state
```

because the distinct column needs to be in the group by, which I don't want to actually do, not to mention problems w/ the select clause.

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: `select state, count(distinct userid) as users_acting from mytable group by state;`

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b` and it's completely unnecessary if you combine it with `group by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that there's a COUNT(DISTINCT( option which doesn't require that distinct value to be placed in the grouping clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) FROM data GROUP BY state
```

Does the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the below format:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) FROM data GROUP BY state
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).